# jQuery rotate cube when the button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation

Why doesn't button make cube rotate?
I am adding +=45deg to it!
Here's the code:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#cube').css('-webkit-transform','rotateY(+=45deg)');
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<button>rotate</button>
<div id="cube">
</div>
```

css:

```
#cube {
display: block;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: #66F;
}
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ysLet/

Comment: It only adds it one time. I need to add it every time I click the button!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ysLet/3/

seems like the += operator does not work in the css line

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    deg = 0;
    $('button').click(function(){
        deg += 45;
        $('#cube').css('-webkit-transform','rotateY('+deg+'deg)');
    });
});
```

this did the trick...

Comment: you should use better names though :)